# Link that require refresh for anchor to work

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I've got an acnchor in my page:

```
<h3 style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px;">
  <a name="taverns_inns" style="font-family: verdana !important; font-size: 0.8em !important; font-weight:700 !important; color: #000000 !important; line-height: 1.8em;">Taverns and Inns</a></h3>
```

I also on another page have a link to that anchor.

```
<a href="/page.html#taverns_inns">Taverns and `Inns</a>`
```

When I click the link, I only get taken to the top of the page. If I then cick on the address bar and press return then it will take me to the anchor but it's no good if I have to do it that.

Does anyone know why it isn't taking me straight there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified and solved the problem. I had a jQuery function running on the page that was set the run when the document was ready which was to late. I moved the script to the bottom of the page.
It works now.